# Ajax Accordian collapses when GridView events fire

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

I have two Ajax Accordions in an EditSite.aspx.  Each accordion has about six panes.  In each pane, I have an asp:GridView control that allows the site admin to perform various tasks, maintaining data. It looks nice and works beautifully, but...

With each update, insert, etc. in the GridView control, the accordion collapses and the default pane opens.  I suspect this is because the page reloads on a postback event.  This is a major annoyance.  I have read that the accordion is supposed to be able to retain the index of the open pane and return to that pane, but with the GridView update this is not happening.

Any idea how I can get the GridView to submit its insert, update, delete, etc. and keep that accordion pane open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the Accordion into an UpdatePanel and set the panel’s property UpdateMode with "Conditional".

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-updatemode-of-the-updatepanel

Comment: SOLVED!!!  

I'm an idiot.  In my "finally" I was forcing the page to reload with a response.redirect.  Removed that and the pane stays open. With the GridView in its newly edited state.